# OfficeJS Manifest Type MailApp - can not use WebApplicationInfo

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I have followed the steps according to [doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_register_app_v2). The application is registered and I have gained the guid which I want to use in WebApplicationInfo to get the OAuth token. Unfortunately using office addin manifest validator (npm -i -g validate-office-addin) I am getting the error

> XML Schema Violation: Your manifest does not adhere to the current set
>   of XML schema definitions for Office Add-in manifests. (link:
>   https://aka.ms/add-in-manifest-schema-violation)
>     - Details: The element 'OfficeApp' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1' has invalid
>   child element 'VersionOverrides' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1'.
>   List of possible elements expected: 'VersionOverrides' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides' as well
>   as any element in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'.

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1"
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>c64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>An Tran</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="MyMeetings" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Find a room"/>

  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png" /> 
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/hi-res-icon.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://contoso.com/support " />

  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
     <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html"/>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>

  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <!-- <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1"> -->

    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                  <Group id="apptComposeDemoGroup">
                      <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                      <!-- Function (UI-less) button -->
                      <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptComposeFunctionButton">
                          <Label resid="funcComposeButtonLabel" />
                          <Supertip>
                              <Title resid="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                              <Description resid="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                          </Supertip>
                          <Icon>
                              <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                              <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                          </Icon>
                          <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                            <FunctionName>run</FunctionName>
                          </Action>
                      </Control>             
                  </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/function-file/function-file.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/function-file/function-file.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="MyMeetings Group"/>
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab"/>
        <bt:String id="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Find a room!"/>
        <bt:String id="funcComposeButtonLabel" DefaultValue="MyMeetings!"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Find a most suitable room with MyMeetings."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    <WebApplicationInfo>
      <Id>c64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668</Id>
      <Resource>api://localhost:3000/c64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668</Resource>
      <Scopes>
        <Scope>files.read.all</Scope>
        <Scope>profile</Scope>   
      </Scopes>
    </WebApplicationInfo>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>

</OfficeApp>
```

P.S. my goal is to have below code working and for that I believe I have to have the manifest file with the WebApplicationInfo element.

```
 Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync(function(result) {
   if (result.status === "succeeded") {
     var token = result.value.accessToken;
   } else {
     console.log("Error obtaining token", result.error);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with SSO in Office Add-ins, but the following docs contain information that might help you resolve the issues that you've described:

- [Enable SSO in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins)
- [Troubleshoot error messages for SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins)
- [WebApplicationInfo manifest reference](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/webapplicationinfo)

In particular, I notice the following info in the docs that may help resolve the issues you've described:

- [For an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#develop-an-sso-add-in), the `WebApplicationInfo` element should appear at the end of the `<VersionOverrides ... xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">` section. (The code you posted includes it at the end of the `<VersionOverrides ... xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">` section.)
- Within the `WebApplicationInfo` element, there should ***not*** be curly braces (**{}**) surrounding the ID value within the `Id` element or the `Resource` element. (The code you posted contains curly braces around the ID value in both locations.) The [reference docs](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/webapplicationinfo) contain an example of the `WebApplicationInfo` element.
- The fact that you get an error (`13000 - Identity API not supported`) when you call `getAccessTokenAsync` with the `WebApplicationInfo` element commented-out is by-design/expected (as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins#causes-and-handling-of-errors-from-getaccesstokenasync) in the docs).

---

**Update** (per additional info from Marc LaFleur):

Per the information in the [doc](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/versionoverrides#implementing-multiple-versions) that Marc links to in his comment below, you might try nesting the `VersionOverrides` element for v1.1 (which contains the `WebApplicationInfo` element, amongst other things) within the `VersionOverrides` element for v1.0, as the doc describes.

Comment: +1 for your effort and time spent on research. Thanks for curly brackets however when I use newer version of `VersionOverrides` I still get the error (see edited question) so I am still not able to install my addin nor get the OAuth token.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you're using a sufficiently recent build of Office that supports SSO?  The [Troubleshooting error messages for SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins) doc specifies the version of Office that's required for SSO.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `VersionOverrides` is a bit a misnomer. It isn't truly overriding values because it doesn't "fall back" to the prior definitions. In other words, if you don't declare something in `VersionOverridesV1_1`, it will _not_ fall back to a declaration in `VersionOverridesV1_0` because [the child `VersionOverrides` element doesn't inherit any values from the parent](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/versionoverrides#implementing-multiple-versions).

Comment: Good info, thanks, Marc! (I've updated the answer to include this info, so that it's more discoverable for future readers of this thread.)

Comment: I have already tried that - I can finally import my manifest with `WebApplicationInfo` the function `run` (`<FunctionName>run</FunctionName>`)is not being executed. I will update the question with most current manifest.

Comment: I'd suggest that you ask a new question for the new issue (run function not executing), rather than continuing to change this post/question. Doing so makes this information (Q&A) more useful for others in the future.