# VersionOverridesV1_1 not triggering ExecuteFunction element

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing a Outlook Web Add-in and currently stuck on the `manifest.xml`. I am able to upload the manifest without the error but the the `ExecuteFunction` element is somehow ignored.

When I remove `<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">` and its child elements the `ExecuteFunction` is working but that is not the option, because I need it to get an OAuth token.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48398770/officejs-manifest-type-mailapp-can-not-use-webapplicationinfo) where we have managed to get the `WebApplicationInfo` working.

So my question is: Is it possible to have `WebApplicationInfo` and `ExecuteFunction` in the same manifest?

The manifest is shown below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" 
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1"
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>c64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>An Tran</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="MyMeetings" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Find a room"/>

  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png" /> 
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/hi-res-icon.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://contoso.com/support " />

  <!-- Domains that will be allowed when navigating. For example, if you use ShowTaskpane and then have an href link, navigation will only be allowed if the domain is on this list. -->
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>

  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
     <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/index.html"/>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>

  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>

  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <!-- <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1"> -->

    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">

        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
          <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />

            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                  <Group id="apptComposeDemoGroup">
                      <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                      <!-- Function (UI-less) button -->
                      <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptComposeFunctionButton">
                          <Label resid="funcComposeButtonLabel" />
                          <Supertip>
                              <Title resid="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                              <Description resid="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                          </Supertip>
                          <Icon>
                              <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                              <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                              <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                          </Icon>
                          <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                            <FunctionName>run</FunctionName>
                          </Action>
                      </Control>             
                  </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
          <!-- Go to http://aka.ms/ExtensionPointsCommands to learn how to add more Extension Points: MessageRead, AppointmentOrganizer, AppointmentAttendee -->
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/function-file/function-file.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/function-file/function-file.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="MyMeetings Group"/>
        <bt:String id="customTabLabel"  DefaultValue="My Add-in Tab"/>
        <bt:String id="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Find a room!"/>
        <bt:String id="funcComposeButtonLabel" DefaultValue="MyMeetings!"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Find a most suitable room with MyMeetings."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
      <WebApplicationInfo>
        <Id>c64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668</Id>
        <Resource>api://localhost:3000/c64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668</Resource>
        <Scopes>
          <Scope>files.read.all</Scope>
          <Scope>profile</Scope>   
        </Scopes>
      </WebApplicationInfo>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>

</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function isn't firing because the version of Outlook you're using supports `VersionOverridesV1_1` but your `VersionOverridesV1_1` does not declare a `functionFile` (or anything else beyond `WebApplicationInfo`).

From the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/versionoverrides#implementing-multiple-versions):

> The child `VersionOverrides` element doesn't inherit any values from the parent.

In other words, declaring something in `VersionOverridesV1_0` does not get inherited by `VersionOverridesV1_1`. You need to include the same elements in **both** sections (i.e. `Hosts`, `Resources`, etc.):

```xml
...
<VersionOverrides 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
            <DesktopFormFactor>
                <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
                <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
                <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
                    <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                        <Group id="apptComposeDemoGroup">
                            <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                            <!-- Function (UI-less) button -->
                            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptComposeFunctionButton">
                                <Label resid="funcComposeButtonLabel" />
                                <Supertip>
                                    <Title resid="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                                    <Description resid="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                                </Supertip>
                                <Icon>
                                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                                </Icon>
                                <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                    <FunctionName>run</FunctionName>
                                </Action>
                            </Control>
                        </Group>
                    </OfficeTab>
                </ExtensionPoint>
            </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
            <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
            <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
            <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
            <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/function-file/function-file.html"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="MyMeetings Group"/>
            <bt:String id="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Find a room!"/>
            <bt:String id="funcComposeButtonLabel" DefaultValue="MyMeetings!"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
            <bt:String id="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Find a most suitable room with MyMeetings."/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
    <VersionOverrides             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
        <!-- Repeat the same declarations as VersionOverridesV1_0 -->
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <!-- Location of the Functions that UI-less buttons can trigger (ExecuteFunction Actions). -->
                    <FunctionFile resid="functionFile" />
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                            <Group id="apptComposeDemoGroup">
                                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                                <!-- Function (UI-less) button -->
                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="apptComposeFunctionButton">
                                    <Label resid="funcComposeButtonLabel" />
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" />
                                        <Description resid="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" />
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                                        <FunctionName>run</FunctionName>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
                <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
                <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
                <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
                <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/function-file/function-file.html"/>
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="MyMeetings Group"/>
                <bt:String id="funcComposeSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Find a room!"/>
                <bt:String id="funcComposeButtonLabel" DefaultValue="MyMeetings!"/>
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
                <bt:String id="funcComposeSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Find a most suitable room with MyMeetings."/>
            </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
        <WebApplicationInfo>
            <Id>c64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668</Id>
            <Resource>api://localhost:3000/c64ded7d-29e6-4083-8afa-351c7a630668</Resource>
            <Scopes>
                <Scope>files.read.all</Scope>
                <Scope>profile</Scope>
            </Scopes>
        </WebApplicationInfo>
    </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
...
```